# Moving array values between enum variations

Tags: rust

My problem is following. I have enum with several variants that use increasing number of items. For simplicity I'll reduce the numbers to first two:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Variant<A> {
    Single([A; 1]),
    Double([A; 2]),
}
```

I want to create special methods which would preferably transform `Single` into `Double`. For example if I call `push_front(a)` on `Single([x])` I need to get back `Double([a,x]`. One way I could do it is:

```
impl<A: Copy> Variant<A> {
    fn push_front(&mut self, value: A)  {
        self* = match self {
            &mut Single(b) => Double([value, b[0]]),
            _ => panic!("Can't convert"),
        };            
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve similar effect without `A` having to implement `Copy`?

Playground link: http://is.gd/i0bQtl

Comment: @ker This title is more fitting, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the constraint from `Copy` to `Clone`; then, the match arm would become:

```rust
&mut Single(ref b) => Double([value, b[0].clone()]),
```

Comment: I had a similar idea. But not sure about`Clone`. My inner nerd yells at me for having too much `clone`. Even though it's probably optimized away.

Comment: there's often no difference between `Clone` and `Copy` (and imo there shouldn't ever be), So you can assume any type that impls `Copy` will have a trivial `Clone` implementation that does nothing more than a memcpy

Answer (score 1):

On nightly you can use the "slice_pattern" syntax:

```
Single([one]) => Double([value, one]),
```

[PlayPen](http://is.gd/F3bBTc)

Comment: O_o: note, this only works with enums, not with arrays directly: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26736 slice patterns are rather buggy (I'd say the label "unstable" fits slice patterns very well)

Comment: It's the more clever solution, I'll give you that. But it's kinda broken :( and I need to modify way Affix works (namely add Nothing variant).

Comment: the Nothing variant is just for safe-rust, you can always use `uninitialized`, since the value will never be read: http://is.gd/6i1MLX

Comment: note though, that that trick is not panic-safe, so it actually causes UB in case of the panic